# Javascript on key press trigger only once

Tags: javascript

I don't know why this appears to be so difficult to figure out. I want to be able to execute code when a key is pressed and held but only once. Instead when I use `onkeypress` or `onkeydown` the function that I bound gets executed repeatedly which is not what I want. How can I have the handler be executed just once when the key is held down?

Note: I don't want to embed logic into the function that will limit its execution, I want it not to be firing the event more than once no matter how long I hold the key.

## EDIT I

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ah7objd4/1/) and the code

**HTML**

```
<div id="counter">0</div>
```

**JS**

```
var counter = 0,
    div = document.getElementById('counter');

document.body.onkeypress = function(){
    div.innerHTML = counter++;
}
```

Notice how when you press and hold any key the counter keeps going, I want it to count just once no matter how long I hold the key, and keep in mind the notice from above.

## EDIT II

Sorry forgot to mention removing the listener is not acceptable, I need to increase the counter by 1 every time a key is pressed but no matter how long it's held.

Comment: you forgot to include the code to share with us

Comment: better to have a code and demo ?

Comment: I thought the question clear but I'll add a demo in a sec.

Comment: are you using JQuery ?

Comment: Did you know, that you can change the login on onkeyup event, to again perform the same action? So which means that using a logic will be usefull.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan I also have an event on key up that is part of the logic of my application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You **do** have to use logic to avoid repetitive events on a key being pressed, because there's no specific and compatible event for key being just pressed.

More specifically, the easiest solution is to store a boolean, setting it true on key up, false on key down (after having done your action), and ignoring the key down event while it's false:

```
(function(){
    var shouldHandleKeyDown = true;
    document.onkeydown = function(){
      if (!shouldHandleKeyDown) return;
      shouldHandleKeyDown = false;
      // HANDLE KEY DOWN HERE
    }
    document.onkeyup = function(){
      shouldHandleKeyDown = true;
    }
})();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/qojiheyora/1/)

**EDIT for 2019**

Now that IE is dead, you can also use [the `event.repeat` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat), which is true when the event is a repetition.

Comment: I was really hoping that was not the case, I swear I can remember I've done this in the past but I just can't remember how...

Comment: @php_nub_qq It's not so hard to do. I've added a demonstration with a counter.

Comment: @php_nub_qq I also recommend to use `++counter` instead of `counter++` so you can see the change in the HTML right after you press the key

Comment: I know it is not hard but it's consuming resources every time the event is fired, I'm looking to eliminate that :<

Comment: @php_nub_qq No, that consumption is so low you really should not take it into account. If you have performances problem, profile your application, you'll see that's not where you need to put your attention.

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated when you can just use `event.repeat` for the logic.

Comment: @Humpparitari In 2014, when I answered, IE was still relevant.

Comment: @DenysSéguret, fair enough, downvote removed. (Edit: when/if the vote lock is removed, didn't know that was a thing)

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to handle this is by using the `repeat` property in the event:

```js
// I'd recommend using addEventListener instead, but
// this is as close to the original code as possible
document.body.onkeypress = function (event) {
    if (!event.repeat) {
        div.innerHTML = counter++;
    }
}
```

`event.repeat` is false for the very first event, and true for repeated events (the ones that are fired when you hold down a key).

Another option is to use `keyup`, which is always only used once, since you can't "hold up" a key, so it's never repeated (but `keyup` is a bad choice for e.g. buttons, because it can break keyboard navigation compared to `keypress`).

Comment: This is such a better way in general to handle this without creating your own state to keep track of what has been pressed.

Comment: This one worked for me, except you should use onkeydown as onkeypress is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ts7w58od/ 
 1. Bind listener 
 2. Unbind when event is fire.

```
var element = document.getElementById('target'),
    once = function () {
        console.log('once');
        element.removeEventListener('keypress', once);
    };

element.addEventListener('keypress', once, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of [Denys Séguret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27645669/6349060) answer

```js
let shouldHandleKeyDown = true;
let n = 0;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
  if (!shouldHandleKeyDown) return;
  shouldHandleKeyDown = false;
  
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = ++n;
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
  shouldHandleKeyDown = true;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Counter</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    Counter : <span id=counter>0</span>
  </body>
</html>
```